# Math.Pow Cannot handle negative value

Tags: c#

I already browse a lot in web but i couldn't find what i need, I need another API or other C# function to handle my calculation.

I have this code

```
var a = //formula that result to a negative value
var pow = Math.Pow(a, 0.3);
//the result is NaN or Not a Number
//^ symbol is also not working if both number is double
```

Please see this reference below for the result of Math.Pow

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow(v=vs.110).aspx

As per this page, if the first parameter is < 0 and the second parameter is not integer the result is NaN, but in MathCad Application, i tried to insert this formula and MathCad get the correct result.

Is there any code or API to handle Power in C#. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the correct question is, what class would you use for complex numbers?

Math.Pow returns a *double*, whereas your calculation yields a complex number of the form `a + bi`. You need a way to handle complex numbers before worrying about your powers.